# Regex that check if string contains at least latin letters and in addition can contain digits in arbitrary order

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex require the string to contain digits at the end, but strings like "aabbccd1bbb3bb","vvvddhh3","12kkk" are also possible

```
(?=(?:.*[a-z]){1,24})(?:.*\d){0,22}
```

Comment: Change `{0,22}` to `{1,22}` to require at least 1 digit.

Comment: Even easier, split your regex up and create a function that checks everything independently. Replace `[^a-z]` with nothing, then count. Replace `\D` with nothing, then count. Ensure it matches `\d$`

Comment: Also, it's not clear; which strings that you presented are **valid** and which aren't? Can you more explicitly define the rules? How many minimum, maximum, which characters are/aren't allowed, uppercase variants permitted?

Answer (score 2):

"Requirements" like "the string should contain at least ..." are written as starting lookahead assertions in the regex language, e.g.

```
^(?=.*[a-z])
```

reads "start of the string, followed by whatever and then a latin letter". The body of your regex can be simply `[a-z0-9]` since you accept both letters and digits, in any order.

Putting it all together,

```js
re = /^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z0-9]+$/

test = [
  'aaa',
  'aaa33bb',
  '2019',
  '#*$)',
  '',
]

for (t of test)
  console.log(t, re.test(t))
```

Replace the `+` with `{1,nn}` if you want to limit the overall string length.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without creating a complex regex pattern. Create two small patterns to remove the characters that you don't want to check. For example, the snippet includes a regex `[^a-z]+` to match all non-lowercase-alpha characters. We then use this pattern to remove those characters from the string, and then we can count the number of characters remaining. This tells us that `aabbccd1bbb3bb` has 12 alpha characters. The same can be created for digits `\D+`. You can then add your validation logic below to ensure it satisfies other constraints (e.g. 1 <= number of digits <= 22, etc.).

This is much easier to understand than a complicated regex and much easier to modify.

```js
strings = [
  "aabbccd1bbb3bb",
  "vvvddhh3",
  "12kkk",
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx12345678901234567890123", // too many digits
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy1234567890123456789012", // too many alpha
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx1234567890123456789012"   // just right
]

r1 = /[^a-z]+/g
r2 = /\D+/g

for (s of strings) {
  a = d = s
  n_alpha = a.replace(r1,'').length
  n_digit = d.replace(r2,'').length
  console.log(`alpha: ${n_alpha}; digit: ${n_digit}`)
  // add your logic here
  // e.g.
  // if (n_alpha >= 1 &&  n_alpha <= 24) ...
}
```

---

Additionally, to check whether the string ends with a digit, just check it against `\d$`.